# How to add registration date and last login date to user list page

Tags: users, user-registration

To assist with managing a WordPress install with a large number of users, is there a simple way to include the date the user registered and they date they last logged in as additional columns on the user list page? Can these columns be sortable?

Comment: WP doesn't track this information for logins, it only does this for currently active login sessions which it then cleans up on logout/expiry. So if you login then logout that session is erased and the last login date is now incorrect, and if it was your only logged in session there'll be no date at all! To do this properly would require additional code to explicitly store the last logged in date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registration date is kept in the `wp_users` table, so that's easy to get.

The last login date is a little trickier. Most plugins which implement a last login date column create a custom meta field to store it (in `wp_usermeta`), update it every time the user logs in, and retrieve it for display on the user list screen. However, WordPress already stores login dates (and related session information) in a meta field called `session_tokens`, so if you don't need last login date to be sortable, you can extract the last login date from this array rather than storing it separately.

```
// add two columns to the user list page
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'my_manage_users_columns' );
function my_manage_users_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['registration_date'] = 'Registered';
    $columns['last_login_date'] = 'Last Logged In';
    return $columns;
}

// provide data for the two added columns
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'my_manage_users_custom_column', 10, 3 );
function my_manage_users_custom_column( $row_output, $column_id_attr, $user ) {
    $date_format = 'Y/m/d \a\t g:i a';
    $d1 = 0;
    switch ( $column_id_attr ) {
        case 'registration_date':
            $d1 = strtotime(get_userdata($user)->user_registered);
            break;
        case 'last_login_date':
            $session_tokens = get_user_meta( $user, 'session_tokens', true );
            if (!empty($session_tokens)) {
                $d1 = max(array_column(array_values($session_tokens),'login'));
            }
            break;
        default:
    }
    if ($d1 > 0) {
        $d2 = new DateTime("@$d1");
        return $d2->setTimezone(wp_timezone())->format($date_format);
    }
    return $row_output;
}

// make the registration date column sortable
add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', 'my_manage_users_sortable_columns' );
function my_manage_users_sortable_columns( $columns ) {
    return wp_parse_args( array( 'registration_date' => 'registered' ), $columns );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code which works almost perfectly
I implement your code but I have some cases where the last connection is not remembered, while I know thanks to the "simple history" plugin that the person has connected. Can you also explain the reason for the @ in front of the @$d1 variable.
Thank you for everything
Frédéric

Comment: Is a "connection" the same as a "login"? If I login on Monday, but then come back to the site on Tuesday and Wednesday and I am still logged in, then perhaps my last login was Monday but my last connection was Wednesday? Anyway, the main reason I wanted to know the last login date was to identify users who don't ever log in, so even if the last login date identified by this code is not 100% accurate, it still served my purposes.

Comment: And regarding the @ symbol, apparently it is an [error control operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). Clearly I have brought this from elsewhere without knowing its purpose. It's probably not needed.

Comment: Also, what you have written is not an answer to the original question. You comments would have been better placed as a comment on my answer instead. Just a note for next time, to help you figure out Stack Exchange.

Comment: I have found a part of answer here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/374955/why-is-it-that-not-all-users-have-a-session-tokens-meta-key-record-in-the-user

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/259897)

Comment: this isn't strictly true, that session data gets cleaned up so it only applies to currently active sessions. If you login on a phone, then explicitly log out, WP deletes that phone login and all associated session data. Likewise a user can click the button in the user profile to log them out everywhere. It also ignores that I can login and check remember me and stay logged in for weeks, it will still only list the first login, so it's not a substitute for "last online"

Comment: @Fred17 do not post comments/responses to an answer as a brand new solution/answer to the question! Even if the site prevents you leaving a comment because you have a single reputation point do not do this, you could find yourself auto-banned as a spambot from the entire stack exchange network via automation

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks for prompting me to improve my understanding of `session_tokens`. I've had a read of the WordPress code and dome some testing, and I can confirm that logging out does **not** delete the row with the meta_key `session_tokens` from the database ... rather, the row is updated. So in the case where a user manually logs out, the date value labelled `login` becomes the date they logged out. I have not tested the "log out everywhere" option though, to see what that does.

Comment: it's a structured data value so there is always a user meta with that name, but it can't be relied on for what you're wanting. However the code is already 90% of what would be needed to support a dedicated user meta, that data just needs to be tracked. Importantly though, do you actually want the last login time or do you want the last _seen/online_ time

Comment: @Fred17 The login timestamp is deleted when the user logs out. I have just answered a similar question which shows how to solve that problem. I will link to it rather than repost it on this very old question.  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/414238/32199

Comment: @TomJNowell — all I needed at the time was to be able to identify users who had never logged in.

Comment: a user who logs out everywhere deletes all their sessions and would thus appear as if they never logged in using this answer

Comment: Again, from my experimentation, logging out does not remove the row with the meta_key `session_tokens` from the database, rather it updates that row so the date value labelled `login` becomes the date they logged out.